# Getting 6th column while handling empty columns in command output

Tags: linux, awk

Trying to get the 6th column value from the output for the row whose 1st col value matches a string. The code breaks on account of spaces.

Tried piping the results to awk, but how do I handle spaces?

`command | awk '$1=="string_to_match" {print $6}`

```
NAME                        ZONE        MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP  STATUS
tensorflow-123456-111111    asu-bsu-b   n1-standard-4               00.111.0.1   00.11.2.345  RUNNING
tensorflow-123456-222222    asu-bsu-b   n1-standard-4  True         00.111.0.2   11.11.3.345  RUNNING
```

I expect to get External IP by matching on name.

```
command | awk '$1=="tensorflow-123456-111111" {print $6}
RUNNING
// Want 00.11.2.345
command | awk '$1=="tensorflow-123456-222222" {print $6}
11.11.3.345
```

Each field value is a variable length string.

Comment: I see you just added `Each field value is a variable length string.`. If that's the case then, obviously, don't show all fixed length strings in your sample input/output - make your example truly representative of your real data as it's supposed to be clarifying your requirements AND providing something we can test a potential solution against. I'd recommend you also include 2 empty fields side by side as a particular rainy day case to be handled.

Comment: Point taken. Will update shortly.

Comment: OK. Something for you to clarify given your fields are variable length - if `<blank1><blank2><blank3><blank4><blank5>` appears in your input, how do you know if that's 3 fields `<separator blank1>[<field blank2>]<separator blank3>[<field blank4>]<separator blank5>` or 1 field `<separator blank1>[<field blank2 blank3 blank4>]<separator blank5>` or something else?

Comment: what is a missing field?  empty string, one space, matching number of spaces with the previous row value?

Comment: Updated. Preemtible is the only field that can be empty. Missing fields are spaces i'm guessing as part of the output formatting for the command. Or may be tabs. IDK TBH

Comment: may be you can use `$(NF-1)` for printing. As the probable empty field is always before the $6

Comment: Perfect @PS. Thanks a ton. Feel free to add that as an answer if you'd like the upvotes. :-p Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Not necessary for your particular case given your updated question but in case anyone has a similar problem in future - in general to handle fixed width input data that has a header with no spaces in the column titles using GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    nf = split($0,flds,FS,seps)
    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        FIELDWIDTHS = (i>1 ? FIELDWIDTHS " " : "") length(flds[i]seps[i])
    }
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        val = $i
        sub(/\s+$/,"",val)
        print NR, i, "<" val ">"
    }
    print "---"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 1 <NAME>
1 2 <ZONE>
1 3 <MACHINE_TYPE>
1 4 <PREEMPTIBLE>
1 5 <INTERNAL_IP>
1 6 <EXTERNAL_IP>
1 7 <STATUS>
---
2 1 <tensorflow-123456-111111>
2 2 <asu-bsu-b>
2 3 <n1-standard-4>
2 4 <>
2 5 <00.111.0.1>
2 6 <00.11.2.345>
2 7 <RUNNIN>
---
3 1 <tensorflow-123456-222222>
3 2 <asu-bsu-b>
3 3 <n1-standard-4>
3 4 <True>
3 5 <00.111.0.2>
3 6 <11.11.3.345>
3 7 <RUNNIN>
---
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, what I eventually went with based off of @PS. recommendation

```
command |awk '$1=="tensorflow-123456-111111 " {print $(NF-1)}'
```